# Is it right to put a viewmodel in a resourcedictionary?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm developing a WPF project, and usually I use resourcedictionary to organize the styles and colors. When using [Expression Blend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Expression_Blend) it will put the viewmodel object in a resource like this:

```
<local:VM x:Key="VM" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
```

and set the datacontext like this

```
<Window.DataContext><Binding Mode="OneWay" Source="{StaticResource VM}"/></Window.DataContext>
```

This is very useful to get the command or property in XAML using the `source` property in binding like this (especially in datatemplate)

```
{Binding XXCommand,Source={StaticResource VM}}
```

Can I put the viewmodel object in resourcedictionary or is it better to put this view specific in each view that is related to the viewmodel?

Also, if I put the below style in resourcedictionary I have to include the viewmodel object,

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Desc}"/>
    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource IconImage}" />
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ChangeShowCommand,Source={StaticResource VM}}"/>
    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the answer: [MVVM Instantiation Approaches](http://www.paulstovell.com/mvvm-instantiation-approaches). Nicely explained couple of instantiation approaches.

Comment: Its a nice list, but I strongly disagree with the author about his opinion on `Option 7: DataTemplate as views` and `Option 8`. Those are my most frequently used ways of tying a ViewModel to a View other than the initial startup where I use Option3 to display the application shell.